# ApolloNetworkException sometime on Apollo Mutation on Android

Tags: android, apollo, apollo-android

I am using `ApolloClient` for Android. Sometime one mutation api failed with `ApolloNetworkException`. Problem is i can't generate in debugging. This exception occurs sometime in live version as i got some firebase `non fatal` log for this. And the message i got for this exception is

> Failed to execute http call

As `ApolloNetworkException` don't have any `code` so i got confused that is it server side issue of application side issue?

When `Failed to execute http call` exception message is thrown?

I only get exception message so i can't figure out whats going wrong.

I am using Apollo version `1.3.2` with `apollo-rx2-support`.

My api call code snippet is like

```
val mutation = ....
ApolloProvider.getApolloNetworkClient(...url...)
                .rxMutate(mutation)
                .map{

                }
```

Please help me to find out the cause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After I relocated to Bali I also faced such a problem. It appeared when I made 1st request from a cold start. Then everything is fine. Do you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet :(  :(  , didn't get any cause for it.